# onclick call jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form with actively populated elements, something like:

```
<input id="id1" type="button" name="some_name">
<input id="id2" type="button" name="another_name">
```

etc.

My options are limited here.

I do not know id, as it is assigned by system dynamically (see: 1,2 next to id), so I cannot call JQ function by #.
Order of elements change, they are shown in different sets etc.

Class manipulation is not practical.
Same goes for any other attrib - pretty much - some are used, some may be used - again - dynamically, so I do not want to mess with it.

I can attach a js event thou (during form generation), e.g. onClick to particular, desired item.

```
<input id="id1" onClick="myFunc()" type="button" name="some_name">
<input id="id2" type="button" name="another_name">
```

I would not need to know id, class or anything in standard JS, since if element with myFunc is clicked, function is fired.

Is it possible to accomplish something similar with JQ?

Comment: Jquery is strong to find elements, and you can bind events (click event in this case) but Im not 100% sure of your question just with jquery you will have a problem to bind the myFunc() on an element that you cant find, do you have a rule of some kind? Like the first button in a form or something?

Comment: do you know names of elements?

Comment: Why would you need jQuery if you can do it in pure JS that simply?
I am starting to understand bobince.

Comment: @haynar - not really | @ zenmaster - AJAX - it's easier in jq

Comment: You can instantiate a jQuery object and call it's methods inside a pure js function. Why would you need a "jQuery function"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can attach your onlick event inline, why not add a class at that point instead?

Adding a class to your input will allow you to hook into it easily with jQuery.

```
<input class="myClass" [...] >

$('.myClass').click(function(){ [...] });
```

**Update**

To directly answer the question you seem to be asking, no, jQuery doesn't have a unique way of firing events inline by using the HTML binding attributes.

However, any function you create in Javascript can be fired inline. I do not recomend this approach since it's outdated and violates the seperation of concerns.

Comment: i'm considering this option - this or eventually rel - so I'm not short of options - but what interests me is there a way to fire JQ function directly from onclick

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see why you wouldn't use attributes as a reference. You could do:

```
$("input[type=button][name=some_name]")
```

Or a generic handler:

```
$("input[type=button]").click(genericEventHandler);
function genericEventHandler()
{
  var clickedButton = $(this);
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: This: ".... Same goes for any other attrib - pretty much - some are used, some may be used - again - dynamically..."?

Comment: what I was trying to accomplish by this post is to find out if there is a way to mimic pure JS onclick

Comment: @Jeffz simple answer is no. the onclick function is pure garbage. You should try to keep your code, content and style separated whenever possible. There are various reasons for this.